Insert proper subset symbol in microsoft word
Proper subset symbols like ⊊ and ⫋ can be easily input in LaTeX by typing \subsetneq and \subsetneqq.
In Microsoft Word are there any similar code to input them?

In Word, you are able to type \subset and see the appropriate symbol because of Word's Math AutoCorrect options.
To reach them, go to File->Options->Proofing, click the AutoCorrect Options... Button, then click the Math AutoCorrect tab. You should see a dialog like this. I have scrolled down the list to show some of the entries relevant to "subset":
:
For Math AutoCorrect to work outside the Equation Editor

the string (e.g. \subsetneq) must be listed in the Math AutoCorrect list and
the Use Math AutoCorrect rules outside of math regions option must
be checked.

You can define new entries in either Math AutoCorrect or regular AutoCorrect by finding the relevant character, or character sequence (somewhere), copying it to the clipboard, an pasting it in the With box in the dialog, then assigning the charcater sequence you want to use, e.g. \mychar in the Replace box, and clicking the Add button.
One way to get the character on the clipboard is to insert it in Word, either

via Insert->Symbol->More Symbols... then selecting the font and
symbol you need and inserting it in the document,
or using the ALt-X mechanism - e.g. for \subsetneq (Unicode U+228A SUBSET OF WITH NOT EQUAL TO), or in a document, type 228A and press
Alt-X

...then select the symbol (you may not need to copy it to the clipboard, and go into that AutoCorrect dialog box.
Both \subsetneq (Unicode U+228A SUBSET OF WITH NOT EQUAL TO) and \subsetneqq (Unicode U+2ACB SUBSET OF ABOVE NOT EQUAL TO) are available in Cambria Math.
If you add an entry in the Math Autocorrect list, it should work in Equation Editor, but will only work outside Equation Editor if that Use Math AutoCorrect rules outside of math regions option is checked.
If you add an entry in the regular AutoCorrect list, it should work everywhere except in Equation Editor.
If you add the same entry in both lists, it should work both in regular text, regardless of the state of the  Use Math AutoCorrect rules outside of math regions option, and inside Equation Editor.
There are some things to consider, including

Although there are built-in lists of AutoCorrect and Math AutoCorrect
entries, they may vary between versions of Word. Further, entries you
define are only available on the Word installation where you defined
them.
If your entry uses characters in the default Math font supplied with
WOrd (Cambria Math), it's probably going to display OK if someone
else opens your document on a different WOrd installation, but if you
end up having to use some other font to access the symbols you need,
other users will need that font.
If you need to "compose" a symbol because it's non-standard, I think
you would have to compose it using either Equation Editor or the old
deprecated Word EQ field. I don't think either of those can really do
the same types of thing that you can do with macros in TeX/LaTeX.
When you use an AutoCorrect entry like this, in Windows Desktop Word
you can select the character and see a little dropdown (cf. the
Equation Editor dropdown) that lets you revert to the string you
actually typed (\subset or whatever). But that is a temporary
option that may disappear and will disappear if you save and
re-open the document. The document does not store the \subset
string, only the replacement character(s). Even in Equation Editor.


Nice answer! This is exactly what I am looking for.

In Word you can insert this symbol as part of equation:
Insert->Equation, select LateX, enter the symbol in the field


Thanks for your answer. But I'd be glad if there exists some code for ⊊ and ⫋. For example, in word we can type \subset and then type one space character to get ⊂.

@Stephen, I type what you propose and does not work for me. And IMHO such symbols assume mathematical equations. And in Word the best way is to use the tool I offer you. It's part of Word.
